# How to get array with rows related to another table for Bllim Datatable - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4, datatable, pivot-table, has-and-belongs-to-many

I use Bllim/Datatables package for the datatables on my web application; but I can't retrieve all the related rows.

I use the code below:

```
$books= $client->books()->where('books.type', 0);
```

And I send it to Datatables::of method as follow:

```
return Datatables::of($books)
    ->edit_column('type', '{{$type}}')
    ->edit_column('created_at', function($obj) {
    return $obj->created_at->format('d/m/Y (h:i)');
})
->set_index_column('id')
->make();
```

But all this return an Internal Server Error (500) with the follow message:

```
{"error":
   {
   "type":"ErrorException",
   "message":"Undefined property: Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder::$columns",
   "file":"\/var\/www\/clients\/myapp\/vendor\/bllim\/datatables\/src\/Bllim\/Datatables\/Datatables.php",
   "line":256
   }
}
```

**MY DATABASE STRUCTURE:**

```
create table clients(
    id int not null auto_increment,
    name varchar(10) not null,
    password varchar(60) not null,
    unique(name),
    primary key(id),
    created_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    updated_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT now() ON UPDATE now()
)CHARSET utf8 COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci;

/* PIVOT TABLE */
create table book_client(
    id int not null auto_increment,
    book_id int,
    client_id int, 
    primary key(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (book_id ) REFERENCES books(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (client_id ) REFERENCES clients(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
)CHARSET utf8 COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci;

create table books(
    id int not null auto_increment,
    name varchar(50) not null,
    description varchar(500),
    type varchar(10) not null,
    primary key(id),
    created_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    updated_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT now() ON UPDATE now()
)CHARSET utf8 COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci;
```

In the **views** I have the next:

```
/*In the view of clients*/
public function books(){
    return $this->belongsToMany("Book");
}
/*In the view of books: (yes, in my case, a book could belong to multiple clients*/
public function clients(){
    return $this->belongsToMany("Client");
}
```

Anybody Know the method for make I need?

Comment: If my question is confuse... I can rewrite it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the next sentence:

```
/* The client whose ID is 1*/
$client = Client::find(1);

$client->books()
->getQuery()
->getQuery()
->select(array('id', 'ColumnA', 'ColumnB'));
```

You can use the `where` clausule also:

```
$client->books()
->getQuery()
->getQuery()
->select(array('id', 'ColumnA', 'ColumnB'))
->where('id','=',1);
```

Note which I used `getQuery()` twice, this is because `Bllim/Datatables` need an `Query/Builder` object.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it throw me an error "No data"

Comment: You're not showing the complete error... But I guess you'll be using the clausule `where` with a condition that returns no row... Could it be?

Comment: Glad to have helped you.

Comment: I send you 50 points of my score ^^ May you teach me about Bllim Datatable? Any interesting URL?

Comment: You can take a look at `Bllim/Datatables` in the Github website: https://github.com/bllim/laravel4-datatables-package